# bash shell output history file location

Tags: command-line, bash, history, output

Where does the bash shell store the actual terminal session? I want to read the output of commands I used before. All I can find googling is how to store the output of a command.

Since output is displayed on the screen, it has to be stored somewhere anyway. So my question is: where?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Bash only stores history of the commands you ran (which you can retrieve by typing `history`). Unless you already have [set the scroll-back](https://askubuntu.com/a/385947/402004) to a very high number, there is no way to see the outputs that are older than the set value of scroll-back. Also setting this value to a very high number will make your scrolling sluggish since the lines are [stored in the memory](https://help.gnome.org/users/gnome-terminal/stable/pref-scrolling.html.en).

To store your future commands and their outputs, there are few options:

**Using `screen`**

Start a [screen](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/screen.1.html) session by entering `screen`. Once you are inside screen, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>a</kbd>, then <kbd>:</kbd>, then enter `log`. All the I/O will be captured in `screenlog` files in the directory where you started the `screen` command.

**Using `script`**

You can start by typing `script`. A [script](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/script.1.html) session will start that will capture all the I/O to a file named `typescript`. You can exit the `script` session by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>d</kbd>  and view the logs in the `typescript` file.

**Using `tee`**

[tee](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/tee.1.html) is a handy tool. You can do something like this:

```
$ bash | tee log.txt
```

This will open a new bash shell inside the one you are already running. When you `exit` out of this, you can see the outputs in the file called `log.txt`

**Other ways**

As Dustin Kirkland suggested in [this](https://superuser.com/questions/186805/terminal-output-history) post, you can also use [byobu](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/byobu.1.html). Although, I have never used, terminal screencasting tools such as [Shelr](https://github.com/antono/shelr) also sounds like an option.

Comment: Wow! Sorry for a non-constructive comment, but I have to say (write) it: this answer is just amazing.

Answer (score 8):

There are lots of questions related to this one, but they all start with the (right) assumption that the output isn't logged.

> So my question is: where?

Nowhere: Bash's (and any other shell that I know of's) output isn't logged.

> Since output is displayed on the screen, it has to be stored somewhere anyway.

It is, but most likely not in plain text and not even on the disk (although this really is up to the terminal emulator): most likely, and at least in most cases, in a memory segment allocated by the terminal emulator.

However for sure it isn't logged to a file, at least not by the shell, and I don't know of terminal emulators which log the output to a file by default.

Indeed this doesn't mean it's impossible to log the terminal output: first I'll mention something that I think not many are aware of, since I've never saw anyone mentioning this at least here on Ask Ubuntu: Konsole allows to save the scrollback to a file (perhaps there are other terminal emulators that provide such a functionality, Konsole is just the only one I know of), although this is limited by Konsole's scrollback size limit.

This is often not really useful though, and most likely you'll want to look into "proper" solutions to log a whole session's output to a file ([How do I log all input and output in a terminal session?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/161935/how-do-i-log-all-input-and-output-in-a-terminal-session) and [Ron's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/759004/380067)).

Answer (score 1):

There is a command named as script , if not installed then `apt-get install script` would do it.

Then in terminal just type script.

and do what ever you want , after you are done just type exit and then there will be a file created at your current directory with all stdout and stdin information.

hope it helps you.

Comment: Package is NA in ubuntu 18.04

Answer (score 1):

This has nothing to do with your shell (`bash`), it isn a feature of the terminal emulator you are using. It is stored in your terminal's "scrollback buffer". I haven't been able to find any clear explanations of where exactly this is stored, but [personal experience](https://superuser.com/q/545129/151431) has shown me that it is stored somewhere in `/tmp`.

As the answer of the question linked to above suggests, it is most likely stored in a nameless file. To see what I mean, open a new file with a text editor:

```
gedit newfile
```

Write a line of text to the file and save it. Now, while that file is still open, open a terminal and delete it:

```
rm newfile
```

Since you still have the file open in `gedit`, you can continue writing to it. You could even write several gigabytes of data into it, despite the fact that the file has been deleted. That's because deleting a file simply removes the link pointing to its [inode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inode). If its [file descriptor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_descriptor) is held open by another program, data can be written to it, despitre the fact that there is no longer an actual link (file) corresponding to the file descriptor on the file system.

All this is to say that your terminal's history is probably saved using a trick like that, somewhere in a deleted file in `/tmp`. What you probably actually want is to simply increase the scrollback buffer size of youre terminal emulator so you can just scroll up and see it. The details of how to do this depend ont he terminal emulator you are using. Most have a command line switch that lets yous et this and many also have a GUI way of setting it. For example, in `gnome-terminal` (the default on Ubuntu) it's Edit -> Preferences -> Profiles --- click on your profile --> Edit -> Scrolling -> Limit scrollback to NNN:

[image: gnome-terminal options screen]

Comment: Interesting insight. Inspecting a longer history in the terminal is not what i want though: I want to have access to the cout to the terminal i.e. all that has been written there FROM E.G. PYTHON

Comment: @DanielBöckenhoff then you probably want `script` as described in the accepted answer.

Comment: Sure. I accepted it :)

Answer (score -2):

Terminal session is stored in `.bash_history` file. Enter this in your terminal `echo $HISTFILE`, this would give you the path of `.bash_history` file.

Comment: This gives only the previously run *commands*, not the *output* of the commands.