# Terminal doesn't show full results when inputting command that yields long results

Tags: gnome-terminal

The Terminal doesn't show the full results when inputting a command that yields long results.

I want to copy paste them but doing so from the terminal is impossible since it doesn't show the full result.

Comment: Have you tried seizing the terminal to full-screen?

Comment: Which version and flavour of Ubuntu are you running? *Please describe with an example what you see!* Edit your question and add the command and the output from the command. You can copy and paste from the terminal window to the edit window. Add four spaces at the beginning of each line to create 'code' style text.

Comment: @M.Becerra Yes, and then using the bar in the right I scroll to the very top but that's it...

Comment: In some terminal windows you can mark all text by `shift` + `ctrl` + `a` and then you can paste it with the middle button into an editor.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are in your terminal, open the Edit drop down menu, select Profile Preferences, and then on the Scrolling tab of the windows that appears, you will see the number of scroll-able lines that the terminal is being limited to. You can increase this number.

Also, using `less` may help you work with the output:

```
your_command | less
```

Your <kbd>Enter</kbd> key will take you down and <kbd>Q</kbd> will exit `less` mode.

**Read more at:**

[How to see more lines in the terminal](https://askubuntu.com/questions/385901/how-to-see-more-lines-in-the-terminal)

Answer (score 3):

You can redirect the output into a file, e.g. by:

```
command > filename.log
```

Afterwards you can read the file , e.g. by gedit (or any other editor)

```
gedit filename.log
```